# Cakephp custom validation on dependent fields

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I need to make a custom validation in my model where the field one can't be duplicated and the field two will differentiate it, like composite key. It's like below.

```
    public $validate = array(
    'field1' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'Can\'t left blank.'
        ),
        'unique' => array(
            'rule' => array('validateNumberType'),
            'message' => 'Already exist'
        ),
        )
    );
    function validationRule() {
    $validation_var = $this->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Model.field1' => 'field1', 'Model.field2' => 'field2')));
    return $validation_var;
}
```

I tried it but didn't work, can be something incorrect in the function?

Comment: never forget last=>true in your rules! otherwise your error messages are messed up

Answer (score 0):

Change your function name to **validateNumberType** as you have defined it in your rule, like:

```
public $validate = array(
    'field1' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'Can\'t left blank.'
        ),
        'unique' => array(
            'rule' => array('validateNumberType'),
            'message' => 'Already exist'
        ),
        )
    );
    function validateNumberType() {
    $validation_var = $this->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Model.field1' => 'field1', 'Model.field2' => 'field2')));
    return $validation_var;
}
```

See here for example: [Validation for Dependent Type](http://www.louiemiranda.com/2010/07/15/cakephp-validate-dependent-field-select-dropdown-input-field/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var $validate = array(
'slug' => array(
'rule' => 'validationRule',
'message' => 'error message'
)
);
function validationRule($check) {
//validation
//$check is value of the field
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $validate = array(
   'slug' => array(
        'rule' => 'validationRule',
        'message' => 'error message'
    )
);
function validationRule($check) {
    //validation
    //$check is value of the field
    //$this->data is value of whole submited form

    // return true if validate, false either
}
```